# New content now showing up when added (angular)

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the app.component, the post-create.component and the post-list.component .
the app.component.html looks like this:
**app.component.html**

```js
<app-header></app-header>
<main>
<app-post-create (postCreated)="onAddedPost($event)" ></app-post-create>
<app-post-list [posts]="storedPosts" ></app-post-list>
</main>
```

the post-list.component.ts looks like this
**post-list.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Post } from '../post'
@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-list',
  templateUrl: './post-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post-list.component.css']
})
export class PostListComponent  {

  @Input() posts:Post[] = [];

}
```

the post-create.component.ts looks like this
**post-create.component.ts**

```js
import { sharedStylesheetJitUrl } from '@angular/compiler';
import { Component, EventEmitter, Injectable, Output, OutputDecorator } from '@angular/core';
import { Post } from '../post'
@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-create',
  templateUrl: './post-create.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post-create.component.css']
})
export class PostCreateComponent {
  enteredContent='';
  enteredTitle='';
  @Output() postCreated: EventEmitter<Post> = new EventEmitter<Post>();
  onAddPost(){
    const post={title:this.enteredTitle,content:this.enteredContent};
    this.postCreated.emit(post);
  }
}
```

and the app.component.ts looks like this
**app.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, Output,Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Post } from '../app/posts/post';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],

})
export class AppComponent {
  storedPosts: Post[] = [];
  onAddedPost(post:Post){
    this.storedPosts.push(post);
  }
 }
```

the problem is that when I press add post it wont show the new post.
any ideas?
edit: also my post.create.component.html looks like this
**post.create.component.html**

```js
<mat-card>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="enteredTitle">
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field>
  <textarea matInput rows="6" [(ngModel)]="enteredContent"></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
  <button mat-raised-button
  (click)="onAddPost()">Save post!</button>
  </mat-card>
```

and the post-list.component.html looks like this:

```js
<mat-accordion multi="true" *ngIf="posts.length>0" >
  <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let post of posts">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      {{post.title}}
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        {{post.content}}
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
<p class="mat-body-1" *ngIf="posts.length <=0">no posts added yet</p>
```

Comment: maybe using ngOnChanges would be a good idea in the PostListComponent. On creating the list the empty and it should update once the output happens

Comment: I have never used that before...I am new in this field.

Comment: https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular's `@Input` would only recognize the changes to it's variables if the underlying reference has been adjusted. Since the `Array#push` doesn't affect it's holding variable, they might not be detected. Instead of `Array#push` you could append new elements using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Try the following

```js
onAddedPost(post:Post){
  this.storedPosts = [...this.storedPosts, post];
}
```

#### Check `@Input` change using `ngOnChanges()` hook

You could check if the changes are detected in the child component using the `ngOnChanges` hook. Try the following

```js
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from "@angular/core";
import { Post } from "../post";
@Component({
  selector: "app-post-list",
  templateUrl: "./post-list.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./post-list.component.css"]
})
export class PostListComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() posts: Post[] = [];

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes.posts && changes.posts.currentValue) {
      console.log(changes.posts.currentValue);
    }
  }
}
```

I've modified your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d6wker?file=src/app/posts/post-list/post-list.component.ts).

Comment: I have edited the question. I would really appreciate if you could take look sir.

Comment: I don't see any reason for it to be not updated. Could you create a minimal working example with Stackblitz?

Comment: sure. I'll put the link  here

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vktysy?file=src/index.html

Comment: this can't be real. It works on stackblitz... but on my pc it doesn't.

Comment: You could check if the changes are detected using the `ngOnChanges()` hook. I've updated the answer and the Stackblitz.

Answer (score 1):

I think this has to do with change detection and that arrays are reference types so you have to change the location in memory that the array is stored in order for change detection to be guaranteed to run.

```
import { Component, Output,Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Post } from '../app/posts/post';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],

})
export class AppComponent {
  storedPosts: Post[] = [];
  onAddedPost(post:Post){
    // the line below does not change the location of the array in memory and 
    // therefore change detection doesn't run
    // this.storedPosts.push(post);  
    // update this way, spread the old posts and append the new post
    // and this will assign storedPosts in a new location in the array.
    this.storedPosts = [...this.storedPosts, post];
  }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

onPostAdded(posts) {

```
this.Storedposts.push(posts)
```

}

instead of

onPostAdded(post) {

```
this.Storedposts.push(post)
```

}

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).